# Artemis symmetric cluster example

Tags: activemq-artemis

I wanted to try out this [Example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/examples/features/clustered/symmetric-cluster/src/main/resources/activemq/server1/broker.xml) of a symmetric cluster of 6 brokers with backup nodes for each live node (as you can read in the description).

But somehow I don't understand, how backup nodes are configured here.

There are six servers with broker.xml for each, but nowhere is a **ha-policy** configured.

How can there be backup nodes then?

Comment: I think this is just an issue with the documentation. The Symmetric Cluster example shouldn't have any backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Artemis JMS Symmetric Cluster Example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/clustered/symmetric-cluster) hasn't had any backup since it was migrated from [HornetQ JMS Symmetric Cluster Example](https://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/hornetq/trunk/examples/jms/symmetric-cluster/).

To build a working demo of a HA Symmetric Cluster, you could take a look at the [Artemis JMS Replicated Failback Example](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/ha/replicated-failback).